# Key repeat acting strangely

Tags: keyboard

Every time I hold down a key, most commonly backspace or the left arrow key, key repeat either doesn't work, or works for less than a second and stops. It seems to stop at regular intervals (independent of me pressing the key), so I have to press the key with a specific timing, otherwise it'll stop the key repeat before it actually starts. At least, that's how it seems based on what I can see. Odd thing is, I'm pretty sure this is also happening on my Chromebook, and ChromeOS is basically Linux minus Linux, so I'm wondering if there's not a deeper reason than anything I can fix.

Comment: If this problem just started recently, as it has for many others, type `uname -r` in the terminal and tell us the result. Thanks.

Comment: 4.13.0-26-generic

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).  Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment here using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling `peaq_wmi` module:

```
rmmod peaq_wmi
```

If that resolves the problem you can add that module to the blacklist..something like:

```bash
echo "blacklist peaq_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But the second command says "Permission denied" even with sudo.

Comment: @JoeyLópez For permission denied error there is another way to [try](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948)